# AngularJS unable to use scope inside a websocket callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, websocket

`$scope` is not working inside a callback function.

```
angular.
module('common').
controller('bidVBoxController', ['$scope', '$location','$element', 'Socket', 'Bid',
 function($scope, $location, $element, Socket,Bid){
  var self = this;
  self.socket = new Socket("ws://192.168.225.59:8010/ws/bidData/");
  $scope.placeBid = function(){
    self.socket.send({
      type: "place_bid",
      data: {
        bidId: $scope.bid.id
      }
    });
  };
  console.log($scope.bid);
  $scope.bid.top_bid_data="sss";//This works.
  self.socket.onmessage(function(event) {
      var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
      console.log($scope.bid);//This doesn't work
      $scope.bid.top_bid_data=data["message"];//This doesn't work
  });
}])
```

A callback function is passed to the `self.socket.onmessage`, which is supposed to update `$scope` variable. But it appears that doesn't work. Please help.

**Update1:**

This controller is used with a directive `bidVBox` and there are multiple elements:

```
<bid-v-box ng-repeat="bid in bids">
</bid-v-box>
```

When the callback function is executed in the first `bid-v-box` element's controller, `$scope.bid.top_bid_data=data["message"];` updates the scope of the last element and not the first one. I have also tried using `$scope.$apply(function(){$scope.bid.top_bid_data=data["message"];})`. But that didn't work.

Comment: Use `$apply` when updating scope outside of angular context

Comment: @charlietfl Please see the Update1. I have stated the main problem. The scope is getting updated. But not the scope of current element. scope of the last element is updated.

Comment: Because angular doesn't know to run a digest when you update scope outside of angular context such as in onmessage callback so you have to tell it to using $apply

Comment: @charlietfl No. The scope is updating. But not of the current element, but the last element. What is the solution? Pls.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be wiser to move the websocket constructor to a service and use only one connection. As written the `ng-repeat` is creating multiple websocket connections to the server. It is up to the server side application to treat each connection differently. Evidently the server is responding to the last connection made instead of each individually. For more information, see [Stackoverflow: Multiple Websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40338457/5535245).

See also [Github WS Issue #684 - Multiple connections, but single `websocket.on("message")` event emitter](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/684)

Comment: But there are multiple server side consumers with paths like `ws://myip:8010/notif/`, `ws://myip:8010/message/` etc. If I define a service and use a single connection, I won't be able to change it to a different path. Any suggestions?

Comment: In general directives shouldn't be making connections to the outside world, they should be communicating user events to the View controller and the View controller uses services to communicate business events to the outside world.

Comment: I just noticed your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53572062/angularjs-passing-a-function-along-with-scope-to-factory). It is in fact replacing the websocket with a new connection each time the constructor is called.